# SQL TRIM/NVL Confusion

Tags: mysql, database, null, trim

I have a question regarding blanks/nulls when trimming and using NVL with SQL(Currently using MySQL).

If you have:

```
trim(nvl(COLUMN_NAME,''))
```

From my understanding/confusion is that you are replacing any null value COLUMN_NAME values with '' which means an empty string? If you trim the empty string what are you left with then, just blank?

Also what is the order of operation is it inside out?

What if you did:
`trim(nvl(COLUMN_NAME,"))`

what does a single double quote " result as? It seems like it is just replacing null with null?

Comment: SQL Server doesn't have `NVL` (nor `TRIM` for that matter)

Comment: Take a peek at LTRIM(), RTRIM() and ISNULL().  Perhaps that will help

Comment: sorry, are you guessing your database engine?, MySQL doesn't have `NVL` either

Comment: @Lamak, no I'm asking a co-worker because I was looking at their query and had confusion about some stuff. They're saying its MySQL. Regardless I just wanted to know if I trim a '' then what am I left with?

Comment: you can test that fairly easily. If you *trim* an empty string (`''`), then you get an empty string. If you trim a single "double quote"...well, you would be doing something weird, because you can't do that

Comment: @Lamak Thanks thats what I needed to know